# Google search in Dutch and results in English

Tags: google-search, subdomain, multilingual, hreflang

My company has an e-commerce site that has 3 languages (english, dutch, german). Recently, we have added the hreflangs, which seem to appear correctly to the e-shop, as you see in the picture. The x-default is in English.

[image: hreflangs]

The problem occurs when you make a dutch search on www.google.nl. Then, the results appear in English (both in the search but also when you click the link) What could be the reason why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing the search on google.nl from The Netherlands?  My guess is "no".

You indicate that the locale for the Dutch site is `nl-nl`.   That means "Dutch speakers in the Netherlands".  If you want it to be for Dutch speakers worldwide you should specify it as just `nl`.

When somebody searches for your site on google.nl from outside The Netherlands they will currently fall back to the default, which is English.